# Mount .vhd stored on ext3-NAS in Windows 7 without copying to NTFS Disk. Is this possible?

Tags: windows-7, mount, network-attached-storage, ext3, vhd

i have an vhd-Image stored on a NAS. I can't directly mount it, because the NAS stores the file in an ext3-system (i read this is causing trouble). I can't copy the file to a NTFS disc, because it's huge, barely fits the available space and transfering would take forever. Is there a way to open the vhd in any other software? I read DeamonTools ultimate could mount vhd files, but this is not for free. Any cost-efficient solution?

Thanks for your help

//edit: I tried the testversion of deamon tools ultimate, and it tells me it didn't recognize the drive or the format. So probably the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Can you access your NAS from your Windows machine over CIFS/SMB?**

If so, you can try mapping a drive to the SMB share, then in attach using DISKPART:

```
C:\> net use x: \\nas\share
C:\> diskpart
DISKPART> select vdisk file=x:\pathto\the_disk.vhd
DISKPART> attach vdisk
DISKPART> assign letter=y
DISKPART> quit
C:\> dir y:
```

Make sure nothing else is writing to this VHD at the time, and expect the performance to be dire.

**Otherwise, is it a Linux-based NAS, and do you have root/terminal access to it?**

If so, you might be able to mount the VHD locally on the NAS and then copy the files that you need to (a share accessible to) your Windows box:

```
~# (yum install|apt-get|ipgk install|your-package-manager) virtualbox-fuse
~# mkdir /mnt/vhd
~# vdfuse -w -f /pathto/the_disk.vhd /mnt/vhd
~# ls /mnt/vhd
~# cp /mnt/vhd/Partition1/the_file_you_want.dat /usr/share/the_share
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first solution results in the same error then with the gui. I will try the 2nd one now.

Answer (score 0):

Today, mounting `vhd`/`vhdx` with built-in Windows tools (e.g. via Disk Management) still does not work for SMB-shared disk images, unless you have true SMB3 (e.g. [NetApp works](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d385f08-269b-4acd-8238-4bed4d1bb024/how-to-use-linuxshared-smb-as-hyperv-vm-storage-in-win2012r2?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv#f40cf909-f17a-48e2-8493-a3f2770f1dd6), but common basic Samba [still](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10159#c22) does not support Resilient handles and thus fails — this is likely to be the root cause, not ext3.).

However, it is possible to mount such a remote `vhd` (but not `vhdx`, sadly) file with [OSFMount](https://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html).

If you don't have SMB access to your NAS, you might want to access it via sshfs with [WinFsp sshfs-win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win).